# How do you use ReflectionUtils to get package private methods/fields?

Tags: java, reflections

I tried to get package private methods/field via Reflections like this:

```
for (Method m : getAllMethods(cls, withModifier(Modifier.STATIC))){
```

but it is empty. Is there any way to filter by package private?

Comment: Do you only want `private static` methods?  Or all `private` methods?  Also, can you post the method signatures of the class you're attempting to use reflection against?

Comment: package private and private access modifiers are **NOT** the same thing. Package private refers to those using no access modifier; also known as default modifier in Java.

Comment: In my previous comment, I meant to say that package-private and **STATIC** are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (Method m : getAllMethods(cls, ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(cls, Predicates.not(withModifier(Modifier.PRIVATE)), Predicates.not(withModifier(Modifier.PUBLIC)), Predicates.not(withModifier(Modifier.PROTECTED)))))
{
    // DO STUFF
}
```

I used the following to test the above. `MyClass` contain 5 methods; one for each access modifier and one static:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("method1() invoked");
    }

    private void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("method2() invoked");
    }

    protected void method3()
    {
        System.out.println("method3() invoked");
    }

    void method4()
    {
        System.out.println("method4() invoked");
    }

    public static void method5()
    {
        System.out.println("method5() invoked");
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
import static org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.withModifier;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.Set;

import org.reflections.ReflectionUtils;

import accessmodifier.bar.MyClass;

import com.google.common.base.Predicates;

public class ReflectionTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Class<MyClass> cls = MyClass.class;
        Set<Method> privateMethods = ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(cls, withModifier(Modifier.PRIVATE));
        Set<Method> protectedMethods = ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(cls, withModifier(Modifier.PROTECTED));
        Set<Method> publicMethods = ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(cls, withModifier(Modifier.PUBLIC));
        Set<Method> defaultMethods = ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(cls, Predicates.not(withModifier(Modifier.PRIVATE)), Predicates.not(withModifier(Modifier.PUBLIC)), Predicates.not(withModifier(Modifier.PROTECTED)));
        Set<Method> staticMethods = ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(cls, withModifier(Modifier.STATIC));

        System.out.println("Private Methods");
        for (Method m : privateMethods)
            System.out.println(m.getName());

        System.out.println("\nProtected Methods");
        for (Method m : protectedMethods)
            System.out.println(m.getName());

        System.out.println("\nPublic Methods");
        for (Method m : publicMethods)
            System.out.println(m.getName());

        System.out.println("\nPackage-Private Methods");
        for (Method m : defaultMethods)
            System.out.println(m.getName());

        System.out.println("\nStatic Methods");
        for (Method m : staticMethods)
            System.out.println(m.getName());
    }
}
```

**PROGRAM OUTPUT**

```
Private Methods
method2

Protected Methods
method3

Public Methods
method1
method5

Package-Private Methods
method4

Static Methods
method5
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to be able to invoke an accessible method (such as package-private), you will have to something like this:

```
        m.setAccessible(true); // bypass access
        try
        {
            m.invoke(new MyClass(), null); // invoke method (you have to know parameter types and pass them if needed. Use *Method.getParameter...()* methods for that.
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve the package private methods you need to query all methods and exclude those methods with `public`, `protected` or `private` modifiers:

```
import org.reflections.ReflectionUtils;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.Set;

...

Set<Method> allMethods = ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods(Foo.class);
for (Method method : allMethods) {
    boolean isPackagePrivate = !(Modifier.isPrivate(method.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isProtected(method.getModifiers()));

    if (isPackagePrivate) {
        System.out.println("package private method: " + method.getName());
    }
}
```

same for fields:

```
Set<Field> allFields = ReflectionUtils.getAllFields(Foo.class);
for (Field field : allFields) {
   boolean isPackagePrivate = !(Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isProtected(field.getModifiers()));

   if (isPackagePrivate) {
      System.out.println("package private field: " + field.getName());
   }
}
```

`com.google.guava:guava` provides an easier and more readable API around `Method` (or `Constructor`) by using [Invokable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/Invokable.html):

```
import com.google.common.reflect.Invokable

...

Invokable<?, Object> invokable = Invokable.from(method);
if (invokable.isPackagePrivate()) {
   System.out.println("package private method: " + method.getName());
}
```

Comment: Package-private are those which are not public, private, or **protected**. Basically, a package-private entity has no access modifier.  Your test case fails if you include a protected method inside your Foo class.

Comment: Yes - of course you are right. Forgot to exclude the `protected` modifier. Edited the answer.

Comment: I would include a more complete class with different access modifiers. It is always good to have as many paths as possible to make sure your solution is solid.  I edited your class to include more methods.

Comment: Actually the example class is not useful at all - therefore I removed it. My intention is not to provide a fully working example project including testcases and output.